# Interpretation of the slope in a probability distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

When considering a certain probability-distribution $P(t)$, then what information does the derivative $\frac{\mathrm d P(t)}{\mathrm{dt}}$ give, in general?

**Context:**

I raised this question on account of a physics exercise, which I could not rigorously complete. In short the question goes like,

assume that the probability of an electron, in an ensemble of electrons, suffering a collision in an interval $\mathrm{dt}$ is $\mathrm{dt} / \tau$. Show that an electron picked at random at a given moment had no collisions during the the next $t$ seconds with probability $e^{-t/\tau}$.

Noting that $P(t)$ gives the probability that certain electrons have not yet suffered a collision, the difference $\frac{\mathrm d P(t)}{\mathrm{dt}} \cdot \mathrm{dt}$ gives the probabilty that those electrons have suffered a collision in an interval $\mathrm{dt}$. We now devide by $P(t)$, to treat the case for one particular electron. So we get,
$$
\frac{\frac{\mathrm d P(t)}{\mathrm{dt}}\cdot \mathrm{dt}}{P(t)}  = -\frac{\mathrm{dt}}{\tau} \implies P(t) = e^{-t/\tau}.  
$$

PS: Please tell me if this question is too off topic and belongs in the physics section.

Comment: This is an exponential distribution, not a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thanks, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is a variant of a standard approach to the derivation
of the Poisson process model.  Let us pick an electron at time $t = 0$
and ask for the probability that it suffers no collisions in the
interval $(0,T]$.  The assumptions are that

(i) in a *very* short interval of time $\Delta t$, the electron c
an suffer *at most one* collision,
and the probability of a collision is $\frac{\Delta t}{\tau}$

and

(ii) the numbers of collisions suffered by the electron in any 
two *disjoint* intervals of time $(t_1,t_2]$ and $(t_3, t_4]$
(where $t_1 < t_2 \leq t_3 < t_4$) are *independent* random variables.

Thus, with $P(T)$ denoting the probability that the electron
suffers no collisions in the interval $(0,T]$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
P(T+\Delta T) &= P\{\text{no collisions in interval}~ (0,T+\Delta T]\}\\
&= P\{\text{no collisions in interval}~ (0,T]~\text{and}~\text{no collisions in interval}~ (T,T+\Delta T]\}\\
&= P\{\text{no collisions in interval}~ (0,T]\}\cdot P\{\text{no collisions in interval}~ (T,T+\Delta T]\}\\
&= P(T)\left(1-\frac{\Delta T}{\tau}\right)
\end{align}$$
leading to
$\displaystyle\frac{P(T+\Delta T)-P(T)}{\Delta T} = -\frac{1}{\tau}P(T) 
~\Rightarrow~ \frac{\mathrm dP(T)}{\mathrm dT} = -\frac{1}{\tau}P(T)
~\Rightarrow~ P(T)= e^{-T/\tau}$.  If the assumptions make sense
in physics (as opposed to mathematics), then you can make
the following interpretation for the derivative of $P(T)$.

> The *tangent* to the $P(T)$ curve (whose slope is, of course,
>   $\frac{\mathrm dP(T)}{\mathrm dT}$, and is a negative number), 
>   crosses the horizontal axis at $T + \tau$ showing that
>   at the *current* rate of change, the probability of no collisions
>   will reduce to $0$ in a *further* $\tau$ seconds. Now, $\tau$ is
>   the *expected time* till the first collision occurs after $t=0$.
>   In fact, even though there have been no collisions thus far in our
>   model, $\tau$ is *still* the *expected* time till the *next* collision.
>   This is the *memoryless property* of the exponential distribution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *the current rate of change*. What does the rate of change, of the exponential distribution, mean, in this context?

Comment: $P(T)$, the probability that there are no collisions in the interval $(0,T]$ has value $1$ at $T=0$, and then decays away as $T$ increases. But, no matter at which $T_0$ you draw a tangent to the $P(T)$ curve, the tangent is going to intersect the time axis at $T_0+\tau$, that is, $\tau$ seconds after the point of tangency $(T_0, P(T))$. This is the same answer as in (i); which says that the probability of a collision is $1$ ($P$(no collision)$=0$) if we choose interval length $\Delta t$ to be $\tau$ -- but of course we are supposed to choose $\Delta t$ to be _small_ relative to $\tau$.

Comment: I just checked your result and indeed we have that at $T_0 + \tau$ the horizontal axis is intersected for arbitrary $T_0$. This is the so called memoryless property of the exponential distribution. Was there a more intuitive way of noting this memoryless property, instead of (in my attempt) calculating it for a tangent curve?

Comment: The memoryless property is embodied in assumption (ii); what happens in $(t_1, t_2]$ does not affect in any shape or manner what happens in $(t_3, t_4]$ for $t_3 \geq t_2$, that is, immediately after $t = t_2$, the electron has forgotten what happened before $t = t_2$ (or at $t=t_2$): the system is memoryless.